Can not make a bootable ISO from an USB Stick for using in ventoy
I did some changes to boot options in my bootable USB stick, adding a customized boot entry.
The USB stick boots without any problems and errors, with the changes I made in the "G:\boot\grub\grubsrcd.cfg" file. The USB stick is a sysrescueCD ISO wroted to the USB stick with Rufus. As the USB stick booting well and works, I would like to make a "back operations" and make an ISO with customized boot options for Ventoy. NO WAY. What I tried?
IMGburn, winimage, dd linux (dd if=/dev/sdd of=/pathto/image.img bs=4M), imageusb.exe
The images are created, but can not be booted.
All other USB sticks I tried earlier, I did with success. Only with this I can not do anything. What can be the problem?

So, you made changes and things worked, and then they didn't? Can you clarify this please? Did the previous stick, before you made changes, work when you used Ventoy to convert it to a bootable disk? When you edit your post to improve it, use the formatting tools there in the editor to add some formatting and break the thing apart with paragraph breaks? These may help improve the readability and clarity of your question.

The answer was too deeply digged in the tutorials, but it is simple.
To customize SYSRESCUE you must use a special command which is the part of the SYSRESCUE iso. So the solution:

First unpack the provided ISO-image of SystemRescue like this:
sysrescue-customize --unpack --source=ISO-FILE --dest=DIR
Modify the contents of the image in the given destination directory.
Rebuild the image again:
sysrescue-customize --rebuild --source=DIR --dest=ISO-FILE

That is all to customize/modify the SYSTEMRESCUE ISO for use with Ventoy.
